# Help linking ideas for a literature review together

Tags: academic-writing

I would like to construct a literature review for an academic paper. I am stating what each paper presents, what their contribution was, and the strength of their argument is.

3  Reading Tea Leaves: How Humans Interpret Topic Models by JonathanChang and others

3.1  Authors

Jonathan Chang, Jordan Boyd-Graber, Sean Gerrish, Chong Wang, David M. Blei

3.2  Overview

The authors of this paper discuss machine probabilistic models for unsupervised analysis of text. They focus on providing a predictive model of future text and a latent topic representation of the corpus. These studies show that they capture aspects of the model that are typically undetected byprevious measures of models based on held-out likelihood. The authors of this paper discuss machine probabilistic models for unsupervised analysis of text.

4  Exploring the Space of Topic Coherence Measures

4.1  Authors Andreas Both, Alexander Hinneburg

4.2  Overview

The authors of this paper present a framework that constructs existing word based coherence measures as well as new ones by combining elementary components. They present combinations of components which outperform existing measures with respect to correlation to human ratings. The authors suggest that results can be transferred to further applications in the context of text mining and information retrieval

5  Surveying a suite of algorithms that offer a solution to managing large document archives

5.1  Authors

David M. Blei

5.2  Overview

The authors of this paper explain how topic modeling enables us to organize and summarize elec-tronic archives at a scale that would be impossible by human annotation. The example shown in the paper took 17,000 articles from science magazines and identified 100 topics. This paper describes  how topic modeling provides an algorithmic solution to managing, organizing, and annotating large archives of texts.

I'd like to reword these paragraphs so that they flow together better. Any help would be greatly appreciated.